# 'User' Object has no attribute 'Ban'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm having issues with my antinuke code on discord.py and I can't figure out what's wrong with my code, my IDE is repl.it and I don't know if it's replit's unstable coding or anything else but it just doesn't work.

The code i'm currently working with is this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_role_create(role):
        async for i in role.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, after=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 2), action=discord.AuditLogAction.role_create):

            await i.user.ban()
            return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=auditlogentry#discord.AuditLogEntry) on AuditLogEntry, the *.user* attribute usually returns a [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=auditlogentry#discord.Member) instance unless gone, then it’s a [User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=auditlogentry#discord.User).

In your code, you could check whether it's a User instance or a Member instance before banning the user, in case it is not a member instance.

If you believe the user is not gone, you may also try converting the user instance into a member instance with the following code:

```
member = role.guild.get_member(i.user.id)
```

Comment: Hello Jevi, I've placed the code you provided into every possible part of my code and it still has no outcome to it, and maybe I wasn't clear on everything including that there's 6 other modules and they all output the same error.

Comment: Can you provide full traceback, please?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/myreplituser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 1656, in on_guild_role_create
    await i.user.ban()
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'ban

Comment: What happens after doing `member = role.guild.get_member(i.user.id)` `await member.ban()`?

Comment: an error referencing attribute error about audit logs

Comment: It says that "AuditLogEntry" has no attribute "member" and without the code you gave me it says "nonetype" has no attribute "ban" or object "user" has no attribute "ban"

Comment: Do you have the MEMBERS INTENT enabled in both your code and the developer panel?

Comment: yea in both.  I don't know what's wrong with it. Maybe ill try it on a new application and see if it works, but I don't think it will.

Comment: thanks a lot Jevi, you're a saviour. I got it working because I hadn't pasted your code right but it still passed as correct code through replit 